# mkString with sequence View to Writer/buffer?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, writer

I can nicely format a collection with `mkString` or `addString` to a `StringBuilder`. However, these methods force `views` to be completely defined, and I have huge `views` that I want to print. I don't want to create those strings in memory, just print them.

*Question*: Is there a **standard method** in the scala library for collections and specially `views`, which has the same formatting as `mkString`, and which can write directly to something like a `Writer`? (Note, I know that I can easily write this method myself, I just want to know if there is an *standard* one)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method in standard scala library. You should use the power of `foreach` method. If you don't need separators, it can be elegantly written as `view.foreach(x => writer.write(x.toString))`.

Comment: No, it can't. You forgot to write separators, which will mess up your code quite a bit (and optional beginning/ending arguments, which won't).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion about separators, I've corrected my answer.